# Don't understand this string concatenation error when dynamically making a filename

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a strange string concatenation error which I cannot seem to wrap my head around.

Here is my code:

```
message = clientSocket.recv( 8000 ).decode( "UTF-8" )
data=message.split(",")#split the string using delimiter
ID=data.pop()#remove and return ID
ID=''.join(ID)#make the list into a string
ID=ID.replace("\n", "")#strip the \n
Pdata=data
print(ID)
print(type(ID))
print(Pdata)
#Dynamically make new filename using time and ID
filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%md_%H%M%S%f")+"."+ID+".csv"
print(filename)
```

The output here is:

```
H3
<class 'str'>
['+2.07767994E-06', '+8.7037......']
.csv0314_185741582956.H3
```

Looks like somehow the first few characters is being overwritten with `".csv"`. I am trying to get the filename correct and it should be `'20190314_185741582956.H3.csv'`.

I cannot correctly open a filename and store `Pdata` in it with that error.
Am I missing something?

Comment: The code is working as you intended, even though there is a mistake in your string formatting(% is missing before d), apart from it it is working fine.

Comment: My guess is that `ID` has `\r` in it.

Comment: You should [edit] your code and create a [mcve] — there's lots of extraneous code in it that likely has nothing to do with to the problem (and that others cannot use to reproduce the problem). We also need to see a sample of  of what data `message` might contain. Without those changes, we can only make guesses...

Comment: '\r' was it..thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable `ID` includes a `\r` character then you might get the output you show. Add another replace to replace “\r” with “” and you will get a better-looking (and valid) filename

Comment: Thanks '\r' was it...I appreciate the help very much.